# How do I get all users from a table stored in an array by date?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this function that takes all the users from an MySql table and stores them in an array:

```
public function graphVals() {
    $sql = "SELECT user_username FROM users WHERE user_register_date > CURDATE() - 2592000";

    if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {    
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username);
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($username);
            $data[] = $username;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        foreach($data as $key) {

            $length[] = sizeof($key);

        }
        print_r($data);
    } else {
        $error              = true;
        $message['error']   = true;
        $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
        return json_encode($message);
    }   
}
```

After that, as you can see I want to return an array which contains the length of the usernames array.

But my question is, as you can see I'm fetching an array with all usernames, each one at one index, what I actually want to do is take all users registered on one date and store them in a single index, all users registered on the date after the previous one and store them in the next index, etc.

How would I do that ? Can I adjust this function to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do :

```
public function graphVals() {
    $sql = "SELECT user_username FROM users WHERE user_register_date > CURDATE() - 2592000 ORDER BY user_register_date ASC";

    $data = array();
    if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {    
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username);
        $stmt->bind_result($date);
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($username);
            if (!isset($data[$date])) {
            // when the date is the first time in the array. Add that date as index for the array   
                 $data[$date] = array();
            }
            $data[$date][] = $username;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        foreach($data as $key) {

            $length[] = sizeof($key);

       }
       print_r($data);
    } else {
          $error              = true;
          $message['error']   = true;
          $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
          return json_encode($message);
    }   
 }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @DorShemer and @Sabari- I have tried this method and this is what I get when run: `Array ( [admin] => Array ( [0] => [1] => special [2] => standard [3] => john ) )` ; I think this shouldn't look like that

Comment: Can you please print the first output of $row means like while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { print_R($row);

Comment: I have posted an answer based on your code and @DorShemer's code. It works fine now. I had to do some little changes.

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding an `ORDER BY` to your query. This isn't mandatory but will simplify things for you

```
SELECT user_username FROM users
WHERE user_register_date > CURDATE() - 2592000
ORDER BY user_register_date
```

Then check the date in your loop iteration, like so:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      $stmt->bind_result($username);
      $stmt->bind_result($date);

      if (!isset($data[$date])) {
           // first time we encounter this date, creating a new array for it
           $data[$date] = array();
      }          
      $data[$date][] = $username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with after seeing your example code. Now I get it by date, as date the index, the only thing is that I had before `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()` when registering, and I get the hour, min and sec too. But I think this is the solution. Let me know what you think, if I should do anything else.

```
$sql = "SELECT user_username, user_register_date FROM users WHERE user_register_date > CURDATE() - 2592000 ORDER BY user_register_date";

    if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {    
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username,$date);
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($username, $date);
            if (!isset($data[$date])) {
                 $data[$date] = array();
            }
            $data[$date][] = $username;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        foreach($data as $key) {

            $length[] = sizeof($key);

       }
       print_r($data);
    } else {
        $error              = true;
        $message['error']   = true;
        $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
        return json_encode($message);
    }
```